# Yii2 - set label position for input field

Tags: yii2, label

I using form field and set label like this :

```
     <?= $form->field($unit, 'estimated_time')->textInput(['style' => 'width: 50px'])->label("Minutes") ?>
```

but label display in the left side of input-field 
How can I display it in right side ?

Answer (score 6):

I think better solution is

```
<?= $form->field($unit, 'estimated_time', [
   'template' => '{input}{label}{error}{hint}',
   'options' => ['class' => 'form-group form-inline'],]
   ->textInput([
    'style' => 'width: 50px; margin-right: 10px;']); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 <?= $form->field($unit, 'estimated_time')->textInput(['style' => 'width: 50px'])->label('Your Label',['class'=>'label-class']) ?>
```

Add css as

```
.label-class{
   float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign style for your input  like below:

```
<?= $form->field($unit, 'estimated_time', [
    'template' => '<div style="float:right;">{label}</div>{input}{error}{hint}'
]);?>
```

more reference
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-bootstrap-activefield.html